# how to control MPMoviePlayerController play time?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmoviewcontroller

I am working on an app which uses MPMoviePlayerController for playing a video.

Now in that I am using custom view for displaying player controllers..
I have used slider for showing the amount of duration passed for video..
now if I want to play back some portion of the video again for which i need to slide my slider back 5-6 second, then how to correlate play back of the video with that??

I am stuck with this issue.. Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks in advance.

Shreya

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by following code..

It may get helpful to others.. here is my explanation

Create a UISlider object in you .h file and in .m file add following code to make it work,

```
    self.slider_Audio = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(VolumeSliderX,VolumeSliderY,VolumeSliderWidth,VolumeSliderHeight)];
    [self.slider_Audio sizeToFit];

    //if you want it vertical

    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -0.5);
    self.slider_Audio.transform = trans;
    self.slider_Audio.hidden = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:self.slider_Audio];
```

and then just run your code..